# Joomla 2.5 remove username field in registration

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I use Joomla 2.5 registration form, but it's massive and I'd like to remove a few fields.
I removed a few lines from components\com_users\models\forms - that allowed me to remove the necessary fields from the screen (username, user, email2). But system still needs them. So I decided the problem with two adding 
$this->email2=$this->email1;
$this->name=$this->username;

to libraries/joomla/database/table/user.php in 183 after public function check()
    
So I need somehow to give a new user a unique username. I have the idea, but it's hard for me to realise. The idea was found on wordpress forum (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52302/is-it-possible-to-remove-username-field-from-the-registration-page-if-so-how) - the idea is to give a user a current timestamp as a username. Can you help me adopt it for joomla?
PS: Please, dont suggest me making a new plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't hack the core files you'll never be able to apply security updates without loosing your changes. (Given that plugins are extremely simple I don't understand your issue)
2. Use [output overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides), ([how to here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)), or [layout overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) if you must.
3. There are lots of "[User Registration](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication)" plugins already in existence on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/).
4. If you don't get the answer you want, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you, I found the plugin from your #3 advice :)